# Solve nonlinear differential equation system (Plot solution)

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, physics

When I solve the system of differential equations I get two solutions for each variable (See the picture). My question is how I can neglect one of the solutions at the plot (The yellow and the blue). Thanks.

Code:

```
sol=NDSolve[{3y[x]-0.5z[x]^2==y[x]*z'[x]^2(0.5+9y[x]),-y'[x]==y[x]*z'[x]^2+y[x]^2*z'[x]^2(18+4)-y[x]*y'[x]*z'[x]^2,y[0]==1,z[0]==0.2},{z,y},{x,0,60}];
```

Code for the plot:

```
Plot[Evaluate[{Sqrt[y[x]],z[x]}/.%],{x,0,60},PlotRange->All,PlotPoints->200]
```

Thnks.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I take your solution with smaller integration range:

```
sol = NDSolve[{3 y[x] - 0.5 z[x]^2 == y[x]*z'[x]^2 (0.5 + 9 y[x]), -y'[x] == 
y[x]*z'[x]^2 + y[x]^2*z'[x]^2 (18 + 4) - y[x]*y'[x]*z'[x]^2,y[0] == 1, z[0] == 0.2}, {z, y}, {x, 0, .5}]
```

sol contains two different solution pairs `sol[[1]]` and `sol[[2]]`

```
Plot[Evaluate[{Sqrt[y[x]], z[x]} /. sol[[1]]], {x, 0, 0.5}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[Evaluate[{Sqrt[y[x]], z[x]} /. sol[[2]]], {x, 0, 0.5}]
```

[image]